# How to ignore all patch versions in Dependabot

Tags: github, github-dependabot

Most packages follow semantic versioning to define `major.minor.patch` versions.

I would like to configure Dependabot to exclude all patch versions and not create PRs.

From [the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file#ignore) it's not completely clear to me how to do this. The example shows the config for specific packages:

```yaml
# Use `ignore` to specify dependencies that should not be updated

version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "npm"
    directory: "/"
    schedule:
      interval: "weekly"
    ignore:
      - dependency-name: "express"
        # For Express, ignore all Dependabot updates for version 4 and 5
        versions: ["4.x", "5.x"]
        # For Lodash, ignore all updates
      - dependency-name: "lodash"
        # For AWS SDK, ignore all patch updates for version updates only
      - dependency-name: "aws-sdk"
        update-types: ["version-update:semver-patch"]
```

How would I exclude all patch versions from being opened as PR?

Comment: The dependency name is a _pattern_, so: `"*"`?

Comment: thx jon. guess that answers it :) indeed to blind to see... :| -> please add it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as jon pointed out, the following config ignores all ***patch*** versions:

```yaml
version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "npm"
    directory: "/"
    schedule:
      interval: "weekly"
    ignore:
      - dependency-name: "*"
        update-types: ["version-update:semver-patch"]
```